# json from js to php - failed to open stream: http request failed

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to send some json data from js to php, and pass it to mongo by REST.

The following outputs json string (that works fine later if I just put it as string in PHP file, please see snippet below).

JS to send json:

```
var s = JSON.stringify(send); //s contains previous data in arrays, etc

ic(s);

function ic(s){
    var ajaxUrl = './iM.php';
    $.getJSON(ajaxUrl, 
    {da: s}, 
    function(data) {
       console.log (data);
});
}
```

in iM.php:

```
$s = $_GET["da"]; // <-- doesn't work
//$s = '{"r":"pax","c":1,"w":["kiwi","melon"],"g":["cat","dog"]}'; //<-- works fine
$opts = array(
    "http" => array(
        "method"  => "POST",
        "header"  => "Content-type: application/json",
        "content" => $s,
    ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents("https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/$db/collections/$collection?apiKey=$key", false, $context);

var_dump($result); // Dumps the response document
```

At the firefox debugger, I can see the file is actually being called, however No data is added.

error_log file is created:
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

I also tried urlencode($s) in php, still not working.
$db, $collection and $key are defiend in php, no problem there.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to dump out the value of `https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/$db/collections/$collection?apiKey=$key` and check, is that url exists.

Comment: Try sending the JSON to `IM.php` using POST.  Maybe it's too big for a GET request or contains invalid characters.

Comment: @lolka_bolka url is correct and it does makes the request, if I jsut uncomment //$s in php I can post correctly.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I tried your suggestion, same result. I have just looked at the vars passed to php and it's adding a slash, something in the lines of: '{/"r/":/"pax/",/"c/":1.... I ended up using and httpRequest, which is working fine. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Basically JSON.stringify(send) function is designed in such way that it will make your json into what you are getting.

```
JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])
```

You should use this function properly. read the docs to know more.
Its basically useful if you have input value as JS array or JS object
which can be converted to single string.

You are getting '{/"r/":/"pax/",/"c/":1 in only case if you are trying  to stringify a json which already in string format.

these:

```
var s = ['1','2','3'];
and 
var s = "['1','2','3']";
```

are totally different things.

If you are sending an array or json object you can even send it directly 
using the code above.
for example :

```
send = {"r":"pax","c":1,"w":["kiwi","melon"],"g":["cat","dog"]};
ic(send);

function ic(s){
    var ajaxUrl = 'im.php';
    $.getJSON(ajaxUrl, 
    {da: s}, 
    function(data) {
       console.log (data);
});
}
```

make sure to handle array at php side properly.
Like if you want return json, do:

```
$s = $_GET["da"]; //this will be array.
var jsonObject = json_encode($s);
```

or you can stringify it there and then provide.

or else just send string and then use json_decode to make it json in php